# what is the difference between the BiometricManager of 'android.hardware.biometrics.BiometricManager' and 'androidx.biometric.BiometricManager

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, androidx, android-biometric

what does is the Difference between these two imports of BiometricManager

import **android.hardware.biometrics.BiometricManager**

import **androidx.biometric.BiometricManager**

Answer (score 3):

AndroidX libraries are libraries to handle backwards compatibility. For example if you use the `android.hardware` one you'll need to use `FingerprintManagerCompat` on devices with Android 9.0 (API 28) or previous.

Comment: is android.harwdware only for specific API level??

Comment: android.hardware uts for API 29 or upper, it's always recommended to use the androidx ones.